# BCP Double-quotes text qualifier output

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp

I have a bcp command that is pushing the results of a query into a flat file that is comma delimited unicode.  I need the fields to be encapsulated in double quotes with the text identifier being double quotes.

Here's an example of the csv output:

```
36029,2,Oct 11 2004  1:01AM,4,23537,0.10
```

Where it needs to be:

```
"36029","2","Oct 11 2004  1:01AM","4","23537","0.10"
```

I suspect it uses the -q flag but I'm not sure how to actually use the -q.  The MS documentation is not doing much to help me out.

Sorry if this is a dupe, I looked hard I swear!

Comment: Its become too late but I also have same problem now and I am not getting solution for the same will get to know ans please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Exec Master..xp_Cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT '"' + col1 + '"', '"' + col2+ '"', '"' + col3+ '"'
FROM table1" queryout  "C:\mcg1.csv" -c -t,"'
```

Comment: Arrrghh, I had hoped to avoid ugly code hacking like that.  Since I'm going to have to manually insert the col names into the query as it is (because we need col headers in the output file and bcp doesnt do that either)

Comment: all column names in the above format you can populate dynamically from the sys.columns.I guess this is the way of dong it in bcp.

Comment: Use quoteName function!

Answer (score 1):

If you extract from within Eclipse it puts double quotes around text and dates. I do this from the view Data Source Explorer. Right click -> Data -> Extract...

Comment: I'm sure the OP wants to automate this process and specifically states he's using SQL server 2008

Answer (score 1):

You can also utilize SQL servers `QuoteName` function to specify the column that should have quotes. This also gives the ability to add any character in place of quotes

```
Exec Master..xp_Cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT QuoteName(col1,Char(34)),QuoteName(col2,Char(34)),... FROM table1" queryout  "C:\test.csv" -c -t,"'
```

Take a look here to learn more

[SQL Server BCP Utility Experts Guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4666.sql-server-bcp-utility-experts-guide.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
            DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(100) = 'dbname'
                ,@TableName VARCHAR(100) = 'example'
                ,@FileNamePath VARCHAR(100) = 'example.csv'
                ,@MaxRowsPerFile INT = 999999999
                ,@Resume BIT = 0
                ,@PrintVarValues BIT = 1
                ,@ConvertDates BIT = 1
                ,@QuotedStrings BIT = 0
                ,@delimitor VARCHAR(1) = ','
            --Generate column names as a recordset 
            DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(8000)
                ,@columnsas VARCHAR(8000)
                ,@columnsformatted VARCHAR(8000)
                ,@sql VARCHAR(8000)
                ,@HeaderFile VARCHAR(100)
                ,@DataFile VARCHAR(100)
                ,@FileCount INT
                ,@TotalRows INT
                ,@RowCount INT
                ,@IntVariable INT
                ,@SQLString NVARCHAR(4000)
                ,@ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(512)
                ,@FileCountName VARCHAR(100)
                ,@PrimaryColumn NVARCHAR(128)
                ,@FileExtension VARCHAR(10)
                ,@Quote1 VARCHAR(10) = ''
                ,@Quote2 VARCHAR(10) = '';

            IF (@QuotedStrings = 1)
            BEGIN
                SELECT @Quote1 = 'QUOTENAME('
                    ,@Quote2 = ',CHAR(34))'
            END

            IF (
                    len(isnull(@DBName, '')) > 1
                    AND len(isnull(@TableName, '')) > 1
                    )
            BEGIN
                EXEC ('USE [' + @DBName + '];')

                SELECT @FileCount = 1
                    ,@RowCount = 1

                IF (OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.#CreateExcel') IS NOT NULL)
                BEGIN
                    IF (@Resume = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        DROP TABLE dbo.#CreateExcel
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @FileCount = FileCount
                            ,@RowCount = [RowCount]
                        FROM dbo.#CreateExcel WITH (NOLOCK)
                    END
                END

                IF (OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.#CreateExcel') IS NULL)
                BEGIN
                    CREATE TABLE dbo.#CreateExcel (
                        FileCount INT
                        ,[RowCount] INT
                        )

                    INSERT INTO dbo.#CreateExcel (
                        FileCount
                        ,[RowCount]
                        )
                    VALUES (
                        1
                        ,1
                        )
                END

                SELECT @FileExtension = CASE 
                        WHEN CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@FileNamePath)) > 1
                            THEN RIGHT(@FileNamePath, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@FileNamePath)))
                        ELSE '.XLS'
                        END

                SELECT @FileNamePath = CASE 
                        WHEN CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@FileNamePath)) > 1
                            THEN LEFT(@FileNamePath, LEN(@FileNamePath) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@FileNamePath)))
                        ELSE @FileNamePath
                        END

                SELECT @HeaderFile = substring(@FileNamePath, 1, len(@FileNamePath) - charindex('\', reverse(@FileNamePath))) + '\HeaderFile.xls'

                SELECT @DataFile = substring(@FileNamePath, 1, len(@FileNamePath) - charindex('\', reverse(@FileNamePath))) + '\DataFile.xls'

                SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @Primary_Column = bb.[name] FROM (' + N'SELECT    TOP 1 co.[name] ' + N'FROM  [' + @DBName + N'].[sys].[objects] ao with (nolock) ' + N'  inner join [' + @DBName + N'].[sys].[columns] co with (nolock) ' + N'       on ao.object_id = co.object_id ' + N'WHERE  ao.[name] = ''' + @TableName + N'''' + N'   AND ((co.is_identity=1) ' + N'      or (co.column_id =1 and co.IS_NULLABLE=0) ' + N'        or (co.system_type_id=36 /*uniqueidentifier*/) ' + N'       or (co.system_type_id in (42,61,189) /*datetimes*/)) ' + N'ORDER BY co.is_identity desc, co.column_id asc, co.system_type_id asc) bb';
                SET @ParmDefinition = N'@Primary_Column NVARCHAR(128) OUTPUT';

                EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
                    ,@ParmDefinition
                    ,@Primary_Column = @PrimaryColumn OUTPUT;

                SET @SQLString = N'SELECT   @cols=coalesce(@cols+'','','''')+''[''+co.[name]+'']'', ' + N'@colsas=coalesce(@colsas+'','','''')+''' + @Quote1 + '''''''+co.[name]+''''''' + @Quote2 + ''', ' + N'@colsformatted=coalesce(@colsformatted+'','','''')+CASE WHEN co.[system_type_id] in (98,167,175,231,239,241) THEN 
                            ''' + @Quote1 + 'REPLACE(REPLACE([''+co.[name]+''],CHAR(13),CHAR(32)),CHAR(10),CHAR(32))' + @Quote2 + '''
                        WHEN co.[system_type_id] in (35,99) THEN 
                            ''' + @Quote1 + 'REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST([''+co.[name]+''] AS VARCHAR(8000)),CHAR(13),CHAR(32)),CHAR(10),CHAR(32))' + @Quote2 + '''
                        WHEN ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(@ConvertDates AS INT))) + N'=1 AND co.[system_type_id] in (40,42,58,61) THEN 
                            ''' + @Quote1 + 'CONVERT(varchar(10),[''+co.[name]+''],101)+'''''''' ''''''''+LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(24),[''+co.[name]+''],109),12),8)+'''''''' ''''''''+RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(24),[''+co.[name]+''],100))),2)' + @Quote2 + '''
                        ELSE ''[''+co.[name]+'']''
                    END ' + N'FROM  [' + @DBName + 
                    N'].[sys].[objects] ao with (nolock) ' + N' inner join [' + @DBName + N'].[sys].[columns] co with (nolock) ' + N'       on ao.object_id = co.object_id ' + N'WHERE  ao.[name] = ''' + @TableName + N'''';
                SET @ParmDefinition = N'@cols VARCHAR(8000) OUTPUT, @colsas VARCHAR(8000) OUTPUT, @colsformatted VARCHAR(8000) OUTPUT';

                EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
                    ,@ParmDefinition
                    ,@cols = @columns OUTPUT
                    ,@colsas = @columnsas OUTPUT
                    ,@colsformatted = @columnsformatted OUTPUT;

                --Create HeaderFile.XLS
                SET @sql = 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp "SELECT ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@columnsas, CHAR(34), CHAR(34) + CHAR(34)), CHAR(39), CHAR(39) + CHAR(39)) + '" queryout "' + @HeaderFile + '" -c -t ' + CASE 
                        WHEN @delimitor IS NULL
                            THEN ''
                        ELSE @delimitor
                        END + ' -T'''

                IF (@PrintVarValues = 1)
                BEGIN
                    PRINT @sql
                END

                EXEC (@sql)

                SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @Total_Rows = count(1) from [' + @DBName + N']..[' + @TableName + N'] with (nolock)';
                SET @ParmDefinition = N'@Total_Rows INT OUTPUT';

                EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
                    ,@ParmDefinition
                    ,@Total_Rows = @TotalRows OUTPUT;

                WHILE (@RowCount <= @TotalRows)
                BEGIN
                    --Create incremental filename for each chuck of rows from table in database
                    IF (@PrintVarValues = 1)
                    BEGIN
                        PRINT 'Percent Complete: ' + ltrim(rtrim(cast(cast((@RowCount * 100) / @TotalRows AS INT) AS VARCHAR(10)))) + '%'
                    END

                    SET @FileCountName = @FileNamePath + Right(REPLICATE('0', 3) + ltrim(rtrim(CAST(@FileCount AS VARCHAR(4)))), 4) + @FileExtension
                    --populate data into incremental filename
                    SET @sql = 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp "SELECT ' + @columnsformatted + ' FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [' + @PrimaryColumn + '] ASC) AS [ROW_NUMBER], ' + @columns + ' FROM [' + @DBName + ']..[' + @TableName + '] ) foo WHERE [ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(@RowCount AS NVARCHAR(10)))) + ' AND ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(@RowCount - 1 + @MaxRowsPerFile AS NVARCHAR(10)))) + '" queryout "' + @DataFile + '" -c -t ' + CASE 
                            WHEN @delimitor IS NULL
                                THEN ''
                            ELSE @delimitor
                            END + ' -T'''

                    IF (@PrintVarValues = 1)
                    BEGIN
                        PRINT @sql
                    END

                    EXEC (@sql)

                    --Merge headerfile.xls with incremental filename
                    SET @sql = 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''copy /b ' + @HeaderFile + '+' + @DataFile + ' ' + @FileCountName + ''''

                    IF (@PrintVarValues = 1)
                    BEGIN
                        PRINT @sql
                    END

                    EXEC (@sql)

                    --update TempCreateExcel table with running values in case needing to abort and restart from checkpoint reached.
                    SELECT @FileCount = @FileCount + 1
                        ,@RowCount = @RowCount + @MaxRowsPerFile

                    UPDATE dbo.#CreateExcel
                    SET FileCount = @FileCount
                        ,[RowCount] = @RowCount
                END

                IF (@PrintVarValues = 1)
                BEGIN
                    PRINT 'Percent Complete: 100%'
                END

                DROP TABLE [dbo].#CreateExcel
            END
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, and no explanation for how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
select col1, col2, quotename(col3, '\"') from table1    -- backslash before double quote to escape the "
```